# Certificate Pinning Issue with TLS1.2 Enabled Server

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, tls1.2

While I am pinning the certificate in iOS and android using below code my callback is getting called and pinning is done, but while server is updated with TLS1.2 our callback is getting called for iOS, but its not getting called in Android.

```
void PinServerCertificate()
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ServicePointManager_ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
            WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(GlobalVariables.BaseURL);
            wr.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RemoLogger.Log("Exception" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
bool ServicePointManager_ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if (null == certificate)
        {
            CertificateValidation.IsValid = false;
            return false;
        }
        string pk = certificate.GetPublicKeyString();
        if (pk.Equals(this.publicKey))
        {
            CertificateValidation.IsValid = true;
            return true;
        }
        CertificateValidation.IsValid = false;
        return false;
    }
```

[Followed below link for TLS1.2 support](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/)

We checked with AndroidClientHandler and Managed[HttpClientHandler], but not getting any solution, please suggest what's going wrong in android.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Which device you are testing??

Comment: sony xperia, android version 5.1.1, model number D2303

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/38843806/2435238. It might help

Comment: not getting any solution, it seems like some configuration need to be change or its a problem with xamarin.